# Why is the character group defined as $\mathsf{Hom}(G,\mathbb T)$, i.e why is the codomain specifically $\mathbb T$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, topological-groups, characters, locally-compact-groups

In the paper *Category Theory Applied to Pontryagin Duality* by Roeder, the character group of an lca group is defined as the topological (under the compact-open topology) abelian group of continuous homomorphisms from $G$ to $\mathbb {T}=\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$. Why does the definition specifically involve $\mathbb{T}$? What is special about it and why is the class of continuous homomorphisms from some group to $\mathbb{T}$ more informative (if it is) than to some other group?

Comment: This has been asked before. You can actually take $H=\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$. $H$ has elements of all orders, so there is always (by the structure theorem of PIDs) en element in $\hom_{\Bbb Z}(G,H)$ for any abelian group $G$, and in fact it is an injective $\Bbb Z$-module (since it is divisible and $\Bbb Z$ is a PID), so it is an injective [cogenerator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_cogenerator) of $\Bbb Z$-mod.

Comment: Note $\Bbb T$ is the [circle group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group). A compact bounded abelian divisible group consisting of complex numbers which allow simple calculations. A better choice than $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @user Okay, but surely there are many nice groups allowing for simple calculation.. Why pick specifically $\Bbb T$?

Comment: @Pedro could you link me to the other instance of my question? Also, thank you for you reply. I am new to group theory so it will take me some time to try and understand what you wrote. Is there a simpler, more intuitive explanation?

Comment: There may be no other reason except that the character group is considered in group theory and Pontryagin chose $\Bbb T$ to define duality.

Comment: I think it's because a lot of the theory of locally compact groups and their representations is motivated by the groups $ \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{T} $ and Fourier theory on their functions spaces. I'm not familiar with the precise history, but I would guess, one tried to expand the theory of Fourier series/transform to more general groups. If you are familiar with those theories, you know that $ e^{2\pi i n x}, n \in \mathbb{Z} $ (for $ \mathbb{T} $) or $ e^{2\pi i \xi x}, \xi \in \mathbb{R} $ (for $ \mathbb{R} $) play an important role. But those functions are just characters to the circle group.

Comment: @m.g. That makes sense, I'm just hoping for more precise motivating statements e.g a concrete property of $\Bbb T$ that suggests making this definition.

Comment: @Pedro It seems to me your analysis of the situation is not incorporating the topology that is present.

Comment: @m.g., Exterior: indeed, the fact that nice functions decompose as a superposition of waves a la Fourier theory is a special case of a corollary to the Peter-Weyl theorem: irreducible characters form an orthonormal basis for the space of square-integrable class functions. One can determine the coefficients (if there are countably many irreps) by the usual method of taking the inner product $\langle f,\chi\rangle$. (There is a very nice question on the site [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735046/integration-over-uncountable-set-of-characters?lq=1) for this.)

Comment: @whacka Yes, I only gave feedback from the algebraic point of view.

Comment: @user153312 it may be a duplicate of my question here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/124379/16490

Answer (score 3):

These are precisely the **unitary one-dimensional representations**. Classifying all (complex) one-dimensional representations of a (locally compact) group is the obvious first step in classifying irreducible representations (the building blocks of all reps, in the semisimple situation).

There is [another question on thise site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717000/why-do-we-want-unitary-representations-of-locally-compact-groups-into-bh) asking why we focus on unitary representations, the answer likely being in its convenience: it allows us to generalize the averaging trick for finite groups and to construct the analogue of the group algebra.

Comment: This seems like the sort of justification which can be given in retrospect, but was not the historical motivation. I don't know any representation theory yet, so I was hoping for something more obvious. Do you happen to know if this *is* the original motivation? Representation theory seems to share the categorical viewpoint of studying objects via maps.

Comment: @Exterior Your question says nothing about "historical" or "original" motivation, and to me this justification *is* obvious. By the way, what historical sources are you using to claim that this is not the historical or original motivation?

Comment: I did not mean to assert it's not the historical motivation, I merely said it suspect it may not be; I could certainly be wrong! At any rate, perhaps I should just learn some representation theory to get a feel for this.